# Finding Blowup of an ODE with maple

Tags: maple

I've been interested in finite blowups of odes lately. I'm looking for a good way to calculate blowup times in maple. Right now all I do is to use dsolve, plot the ode, and then look where the solution appears to blowup. Unfortunately, this is rather cumbersome for my computer to handle for the odes I'm interested in. Just wondering if someone knew of another way to calculate the blowup times. I can use other math programs as well, I'm just most comfortable with maple. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by blowup?

Comment: @Amzoti typically, when a solution goes to $\infty$ in finite time.

Comment: If it is a nonlinear problem there is no easy way. If it is linear then you look for times where coefficients blow up. There are standard theorems for this case.

Answer (score 1):

At least in Maple 16, `dsolve` tells me about singularity explicitly, without me having to look at the graph. For example:

```
IVP:=[diff(w(t),t$4)+w(t)^3=0, w(0)=0, D(w)(0)=0, (D@@2)(w)(0)=0, (D@@3)(w)(0)=1];
dsolve(IVP, w(t), numeric,  range=0..6);
```

Result:

> Warning, cannot evaluate the solution further right of 5.5472807, probably a singularity.

Or, for the equation you were originally interested in:

```
IVP:=[diff(w(t),t$4)+diff(w(t),t$2)+w(t)^3=0, w(0)=0, D(w)(0)=0, (D@@2)(w)(0)=0, (D@@3)(w)(0)=1];
dsolve(IVP, w(t), numeric,  range=0..7);
```

Result:

> Warning, cannot evaluate the solution further right of 6.2805222, probably a singularity

Hm, that looks suspiciously close to $2\pi$...

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful, but I was wondering if there was a way for maple to search for a singularity like this instead of using dsolve as that uses a lot of memory if the blowup doesn't occur for a long time.

Comment: @John I don't know if it has a "search for singularity" command, but you can try to use dsolve several times: say, on $[0,1]$, then on $[1,2]$ (with initial conditions obtained at previous step), etc. Presumably, each step will use less memory, and after it's done everything except for the values at the right endpoint can be forgotten.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried matlab? I calculate the follows: dsolve('D4y+D2y+y^3=0','y(0)=0','Dy(0)=1','D2y(0)=0','D3y(0)=0')

I also have tried sevral ICs, but it said there is no solutions. Also ODE23 ODE45 can be used. Good luck.