# How to find out where a solution to a differential equation is defined?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a question concerning 1st order ODE's:

Let me assume that we have an ODE $y'(t)=g(y(t))+h(t)$.

And now I am asked to solve it and then determine where the solution is defined.
Actually I do not know whether the question "where a solution is defined" is just a property of the parameter or also of the initial condition?- I guess both?

Now I was wondering whether the last thing is just a property of the solution or also of the process of solving this ODE. So what I am actually asking is: How would one do this? My idea was to write down each restriction to the solution that could occur on the way to the solution of the ODE. So if I had to divide by y somewhere but the solution would be totally okay with y=0, I would still have to cross it out.

Comment: Have you read the [Picard–Lindelöf theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem)?

Comment: what are you trying to tell me?

Comment: The answer to your question is that theorem. Any ODE book will have a detailed proof, along with the relation between existence, uniqueness and continuation of solutions depending on parameters and initial conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do not know whether the question "where a solution is defined" is just a property of the parameter or also of the initial condition?- I guess both?

Yes, of both. A simple example: $y'=cy^2$, $y(0)=y_0$. Assuming $c>0$ and $y_0>0$, the solution is $$y=\frac{1}{y_0^{-1}-ct}$$
which ceases to exist (blows up) at $y=1/(cy_0)$. The blow-up time depends on both $c$, a parameter in the equation, and the initial condition $y_0$. Informally: the faster it grows and the bigger it is to begin with, the faster it will blow up.

> a property of the solution or also of the process of solving this ODE

As solution is unique (which it usually is, by Picard–Lindelöf), the blow-up times, both forward  and backward  in time, are uniquely determined by  the initial value problem.  They do not depend on how we solve the equation. The *maximal interval of existence*  of solution is located between two blow-up times: $(T_b,T_f)$. In my example it is $(-\infty, 1/(cy_0))$, since there is no blow-up going backward in time.

> How would one do this?

There is no recipe. If you can solve the equation, like I did above, you're in luck. Otherwise, the precise location of blow-up, or even a proof that it happens in finite time, require nontrivial work. Numerical routines may give an approximate time (not 100% reliable). See [Finding Blowup of an ODE with maple](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/389640).